# GIT fetch/merge and push cycle - causes additional commits to be created - why?

Tags: git

I am working to get my group using git (were using svn). We have a 'central' system with a bare repository as our shared/backup system. There are 2 respositories at the moment, both for testing git - call them A and B. To start things off simply, we're using this cycle (and only 2 people are testing so far):

```
- edit and commit
- git fetch origin
- git diff origin/master master # to see what merge will do
- git merge origin/master master  # merge
- git push   # share the merged commit
```

For repository A, if one person makes a change, then the other does the fetch/merge/push, the state of things 'settles down' to where both people show 'Everything up-to-date' for `git push`.

However in repository B we have a 'ping pong' effect that keeps producing new merge comments. gitk shows one commit as "merge branch 'master', remote branch origin/master" and the next says "merge branch 'master', remote-TRACKING branch origin/master". [I put TRACKING in caps to show the difference.] The 'git remote show origin' show the same info for both users.

I'm sure the problem is obvious to one of you GIT pro's - please enlighten us! Thanks.

Comment: You could make this a lot clearer by posting ascii art (or a screen shot from gitk) indicating the history with the "undesirable" merges. (It sounds like you might have a commit in B that's never been pushed, but it's difficult to tell from the information you've given.)

Comment: Gitk shows just a straight line, with alternating commits, one per user. (Remember we are just testing.) The commits show alternating messsages with and w/o the 'TRACKING' I noted above, otherwise appear identical. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Do gitk --all, then you will see all the branches note only master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to the fact that you're incorrectly using the merge command:

```
git merge branch1 topic
```

is going to produce an "octopus" merge which has more than two parents.

Instead for merge you should use:

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
```

Another possibility is that if two persons are working on  repo B and they follow your scenario by the book - they will have this problem of merge commits appearing all the time.
In case if you're developing in master branch and you know that somebody else might have updated it you should use (you are in master branch):

```
git commit ...
git fetch origin
git diff origin/master master
git rebase origin/master
```

That will streamline the history.

Now shorter variant of this will be (if you're ok to review diffs later):

```
git commit 
git pull --rebase
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: We are actually using only master, so the 'master' on the merge should be redundant, right? Ie `git merge origin/master master' should be the same as 'git merge origin/master' if you're on the master branch(?) We are also looking at rebase but trying to understand one thing at a time. Thanks.

Comment: Or is `git merge origin/master master` taken the 2nd master as a second commit (to be merged into the current branch - which is master)? Still puzzling over the man page.

Comment: Nope, it is different. you're confusing the syntax of commands like git diff point1 point2 with git merge. I.e. git merge is working with current branch always, therefore "git merge origin/master master" has different meaning than "git merge origin/master". In your case it says - take current branch whatever it is and merge two other branches in it origin/master and master, see section examples http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-merge

Comment: Looking at the gitk output, it looks like the 2nd 'master' on the merge was messing it up. But now I can't reproduce it - it seems to be ignoring the second 'master' and it has stopped the behavior. Not sure what was wrong(!) Thanks for your assistance on catching the error!

Comment: yes, you second comment is correct understanding of what is going on